# I can't install from Delphi 10.3.3 Android 32/64 on Android 11 device

Tags: android, delphi, installation, rio

I can't install a Delphi 10.3.3 Android 32/64-bit app on an Android 11 device.

I'm getting this error:

```
Performing Streamed Install.

adb: failed to install H:\Mis documentos\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\x2\Android64\Debug\TabbedwithNavigation\bin\TabbedwithNavigation.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/~~DFtbsqRNmIVX6qX7FlFJWg==/com.embarcadero.TabbedwithNavigation-0B50fmmgUibrpy3czY56dg==/base.apk code is missing]
```

My configuration is:

Delphi 10.3.3
SDK android 25.2.5 32/64-bit (android 26) stock
Android SDK 26.1.1 32/64-bit (Android 29)

In all cases, I receive the same error.

**I'm doing:**

```
\File\New\Multi-device application-Delphi
Select Tabbed
Run with debug
```

Comment: Android 11 support requires that you build against API 30.  If you want to upload to the Play store, you also need to [build against API 30](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk).